# How to use a generic method

Tags: java

Sorry if this is stupid question but i have the following method...

```
static <V> V[] getRange(V[] arr, V val, int range) {
    ArrayList<V> inRange = new ArrayList<>();
    int index = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        if (arr[i] == val)
            index = i;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        if (Math.abs(i - index) <= range)
            inRange.add(arr[i]);
    return (V[]) inRange.toArray();
}
```

With this method you're supposed to be able to supply an element and a range, and return an array with nearby values. For example in psuedocode this what should happen.

```
getRange({1,2,3,4,5,6}, 5, 2) = {3,4,5,6}
```

However if i try to use this method with an int i get the following message:

> The method getRange(V[], V, int) in the type myType is not
>   applicable for the arguments (int[], int, int)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#instantiate

Comment: Primitive types will be implicitly converted to wrappers where applicable - however, the same cannot be said for arrays.  You'll have to use an array of the Integer type. 

    Integer[] range = getRange(new Integer[]{1,2,3,4,5,6}, 5, 2);

Also, your generic method currently has a void return type instead of V[].

Comment: Is there a generic method for converting primitive[] to wrapper[]?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because a primitive cannot be used as a generic value.
Try with the `Integer` class, it should be ok.

Comment: I think you meant to write something else when you wrote "a primitive cannot be a primitive".